# Perform recurrent tasks in Rails without loading the full environment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, cron, whenever

In my application, I need to execute a task every 5 minutes. The task itself is quite lean, so that's not the problem: the point is that loading the Rails environment uses almost all the CPU of the server. Right now, I'm using `whenever` with a code like this in my `schedule.rb`:

```
every 5.minutes do
  runner Task.perform
end
```

But the cost is too big. Is there anyway to execute this kind of tasks in a preloaded environment? Or any other better solution?

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a background process (many gems, notably [delayed job](http://www.tobinharris.com/past/2009/3/9/6-ways-to-run-background-jobs-in-rubyonrails/)) and implementing a simple "cron" in your code with a polling loop something like

```
def perform
  last = Time.now
  while true
    if last.sec % (5 * 60) != 0
      do_task
      last = Time.now
    end
  end
end
```

Warning: this example has more holes than a slice of swiss cheese.  Write something better :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use a cron job or set it up to run in a bash script. These would have the advantage of not being tied to your application.

Comment: That's what `whenever` does.  If I read the OP's question correctly, the problem is the cost of loading the entire Rails stack every five minutes.